# PyCharm/ IntelliJ IDEA run configuration assume AWS role with MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, pycharm, multi-factor-authentication, assume-role

In PyCharm i want to create run/ debug configuration for project that must have access to AWS resources. But first AWS user must assume the role that gives permissions, and assuming the role needs MFA.

Now i first run CLI `assume-role` command, than copy-paste temporary role credentials to environment variables in the run/ debug configuration. But duration of the assumed role is too short, and this process need to be repeated time-by-time, and it isn't very useful.

So- what is the best way to configure PyCharm/ IntelliJ IDEA in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So best solution i found is:

- Run in terminal AWS CLI `assume-role` command ([assume-role descroption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html)). After execution of this command environment variables with temporary role credentials are created: `AWS_ROLE_NAME`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and  `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`.
- Get values of these variables (for example by using `export` command).
- Set these variables as user environment variables in PyCharm/ IDEA run/debug configuration.
  Application will run with desirable role permissions.